# showing errors using foreach laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am following a tutorial on laravel 5 at laracasts, [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/12) and I am having problems with showing the errors that occur when I try to validate the form. The program works as it should, in the terms of not going to the next page when the form is submitted, but i want to show some feedback USING the **$errors** variable. I do NOT want to use customized messages.

My problem is that in the tutorial the **$errors** is treated as an array and it works there, but not on my computer. The variable seems to be of type object.

Here is what is says when I var_dump it.

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#163 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> 
array(1) { ["default"]=> object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#164 (2) 
{ ["messages":protected]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
string(28) "The title field is required." } ["body"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
string(27) "The body field is required." } } ["format":protected]=> 
string(8) ":message" } } }
```

When i use this code as is shown in the tutorial it just creates the list without any elements in it.

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <ul class="alert alert-danger">
     @foreach ($errors as $error)
        <li>
           {{$error}}
        </li>
     @endforeach

  </ul>

@endif
```

Now, I have tried to access the elements using

```
$errors->bags["default"]->messages["title"]
```

but without any results. I have tried **$errors->all()** too.

**$errors->all()** worked but the problem was that I needed to clear the compiled views using

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: You probabaly need `$errors->all()`

Comment: I have tried that too.

Comment: At any rate the tutorial also uses `$errors->all()` (at around 9:17) you probably need to go through it again more carefully in case you missed something else like how to pass the errors to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$errors->all()** worked but the problem was that I needed to clear the compiled views using

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $errors->all() ? In [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) documentation they use it like this:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```